# jdbc executeUpdate fail in autocommit mode

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, commit, sqlexception

in autocommit mode on postgresql database, if jdbc executeUpdate throws SQLException it means that no data on database was modify? or i should set autocommit to false and manage it manually?

Answer (score 1):

> When a connection is created, it is in autocommit mode. This means
>   that each individual SQL statement is treated as a transaction and is
>   automatically committed right after it is executed. This is true for
>   all JDBC drivers, including the PostgreSQL's one. **To start a new
>   transaction, we turn the autocommit off.**

To read more and for sample code, check: http://zetcode.com/db/postgresqljavatutorial/

Comment: I know what it means autocommit, i just would know what happen on database if in my java code sqlexception it's thrown by executeUpdate(). javadoc says:

SQLException - if a database access error occurs; this method is called on a closed PreparedStatement or the SQL statement returns a ResultSet object

this means that no data were modify by my statement?